# CMD find specific folder in subfolders and CD into it

Tags: windows, command-line

I am tinkering a bit with CMD and I have a folder called images on my D drive and the folder is stored in a bunch of subfolders, I want to run a CMD command that will look for the folder and then CD into it.

This is my current command:

```
DIR /A-D /B /S "images"
```

It find the path to images but that is about how far I have managed to make it so far, how can I CD into that path using the command above?

Comment: the attribute `/A-D` will look for files not directories.

Answer (score 1):

As LotPings mentioned in his comment, there are some slight issues with the way that you’re using the `/A` switch in your command. It should actually be `/AD` because `-D` means to exclude directories.

Once that is fixed, you can wrap your command in a `for` loop like below:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('DIR /AD /B /S "images"') do cd "%a"
```

If you want to use this in a batch file, you would need to escape the `%` with another `%` like so:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('DIR /AD /B /S "images"') do cd "%%a"
```

Although you may only get one result from your `dir` command, the `for` loop makes it easy to get this information into a variable. It would just cause some issues if you have more than one “images” folder in your directory structure. In that case you would need to add some logic to figure out which one is the one you want.

**Further reading:**

- [For - SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [Dir - SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)

Comment: In DIR switches specifying an attribute, that start with `/A`, such as D (directories), H (hidden) etc, the colon for an inclusive result is optional, thus `DIR /A:D` and `DIR /AD` are equivalent. The dash for an exclusive result is not optional.